# Передача данных из формы Spring

Tags: java, spring

У меня есть форма, в которой th:object не находит нужный объект и подсвечен красным, из-за чего передача данных и не работает. В чем может быть ошибка?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${registrationRequest}" method="post">
    <div><label> Email : <input type="text"  th:field="*{login}"  name="login"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> Password: <input type="password"  th:field="*{password}" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Есть класс RegistrationRequest

```
   @Data
public class RegistrationRequest {

    @NotEmpty
    private String login;

    @NotEmpty
    private String password;


}
```

Есть метод регистрации в контроллере

```
@PostMapping(value="/register")
public String registerUser(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest registrationRequest) throws UserException {
    UserEntity u = new UserEntity();
    if(registrationRequest.getLogin()!=null) {
        if(registrationRequest.getPassword()!=null) {
            u.setPassword(registrationRequest.getPassword());
            u.setLogin(registrationRequest.getLogin());
            u.setActivationCode(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            userService.saveUser(u);
            String message = String.format(
                    "Hello, %s! \n" +
                            "Welcome to Sweater. Please, visit next link: http://localhost:8080/activate/%s",
                    u.getLogin(),
                    u.getActivationCode()
            );

            // mailSender.send(u.getLogin(),"Activation code",message);
            return "User is created";
        }
        else throw new UserException("Incorrect password");
    }
    else throw new UserException("Incorrect login");

}
```

Comment: а где метод контроллера для обработки GET запроса??

Comment: с пользовательскими запросами разобрались то?

Comment: может, потому что вы указали имя класса `RegistrationRequest`, а не объекта `registrationRequest`?